# When is it true that a group of order n is unique up to isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

A group of prime order is cyclic and so unique.

But is this the only possibility?

How do you characterize finite group of order $n$ for which it is unique up to isomorphism?

As pointed out by friend earlier, if $n=pq$ is composite, then $C(p) \times C(q)$ is not isomorphic to $C(n)$ and we are done.

But Here is a theorem:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then the cyclic group $C(n)$ of order $n$ is
>   the only group of order $n$ if and only if one has $(n, \phi(n)) = 1,$ where
>   $\phi$ denotes the Euler phi function.

I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: There is a [partial answer](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/10/03/cyclic-groups-of-composite-order/) for semiprime group orders.

Comment: I can't seeeeeeeee:  403 Forbidden
WHAT? Why am I seeing this?

Your access to this site was blocked by Wordfence, a security provider, who protects sites from malicious activity.

If you believe Wordfence should be allowing you access to this site, please let them know using the steps below so they can investigate why this is happening.
Reporting a Problem

Comment: [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/allgrouporderncyclic.pdf) is a paper which classifies all $n$ for which all groups of order $n$ are cyclic.  worth remarking:  your friend's comment is not correct.  All groups of order $15=3\times 5$ are cyclic, for example.

Comment: Note that your statement "if $n=pq$ is composite, then $C(p)\times C(q)$ is not isomorphic to $C(n)$" is false.  In fact, if $p \neq q$ are primes, then we _always_ have $C(p)\times C(q) \cong C(pq)$